# How do i get the string within<> "hi<helloeveryone.c>"

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to get the string inside angle brackets using python.
I want "helloeveryone.c" as output
Please let me know i am new to python

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried, in the form of a [mre], and [edit] your question accordingly?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use String's [`find`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp) method:

```
In [565]: s = "hi<helloeveryone.c>"

In [567]: s[s.find("<")+1:s.find(">")]
Out[567]: 'helloeveryone.c'
```

**Explanation:**

Slice the `string` from index where you find `<` to the index of `>`.

**EDIT:**

Use `split` method:

```
In [572]: s[s.find("<")+1:s.find(">")].split('.')[0]
Out[572]: 'helloeveryone'
```

Comment: This code will be incomprehensible to someone who is new to python.

Comment: @AfterVirtue Have added some explanation. Please check.

Comment: Ok now how to remove .C from that string